# cannot change the code for my ajax content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Sup, right so I'm using this script from Tutorialzine.
And basically the basic set up for a link is:

/page_number.php

and the link itself is; pagenumber

But I cant link anything other than page_number.php and I need to know how I can change the script so that I can link any link on my site without it messing up.

Here's the code;

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
<a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
<a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
<a href="#page4">Page 4</a>



    <div id="pageContent">
    Hello, this is a demo for a <a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/" target="_blank">Tutorialzine tutorial</a>. To test it, click some of the buttons above. Have a nice stay!</div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var default_content="";

$(document).ready(function(){

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){

            checkURL(this.hash);

    });

    //filling in the default content
    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();


    setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;

        // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
        // fill the pageContent with the default_content

        if(hash=="")
        $('#pageContent').html(default_content);

        else
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}


function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

load_page.php

```
<?php

if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('page_'.$page.'.php'))
echo file_get_contents('page_'.$page.'.php');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

Any help will be really appreciated...

Comment: Well you need to bind to links with the hash, not all.

Comment: sorry im fairly new to this sort of coding, how would I do it :/?

Answer (score 0):

As per @epascarello's comment, you need to bind your function to link that point to an hash by doing the following:

```
// bind to <a> that have their href attribute start with #
$('ul li a[href^=#]').click(function (e) { 
    checkURL(this.hash);
});
```